# How do I change notice & alert's class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to adjust the standard application template in Rails to insert a class around the notice and alert messages, but I can't seem to find an elegant way of doing it.

At present, I have the scaffold:

```
  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

I want it to only show the surrounding tags if a notice or alert is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `if` statement.

```
<% if notice %>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, :id => "flash_#{name}", :class => "my_class" do %>
    <%= msg %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Define styling for the `.my_class`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the parts in if like this:

```
<% if alert %>
   <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>
```

You can also use `unless` if you like